# Formulario devuelve [object Object]

Tags: angular, formularios, typescript

Estoy creando un formulario de login en Angular. El form tiene dos campos: **user** y **password**. Ahora quiero simplemente capturar estos inputs e imprimirlos en la consola. Sin embargo, me arroja `[object Object]`. Os muestro el código:

El form:

```
<form #formLogin="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onLoginEasy(formLogin)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user">User</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</form>
```

La función que debe imprimir en la consola:

```
onLoginEasy(value) {
    console.log('Valores= ' + value);
  }
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: el value  del form son todos los campos que se encuentra en el formulario con sus valores. porque no intentas con un console.table(value)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Me muestra una tabla con todas las propiedades del formulario, pero no hay rastro de los valores de los campos user y password.

Comment: lo ideal agrega `[(ngModel)]="model.user"` y  `[(ngModel)]="model.password"` luego en tu funcion de submit coloca `console.log(this.model)` y alli lo tienes